# Emberjs is not returning data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Im trying to make a search from my component when the customer select an option. But my component its not loading the data when I use filters on it but without filters it work... This is my code.

> My component country-list.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(), 
  iso3: null,
  valuesIso: null,
  actions: {
    countryIso() { 
      this.set("iso3", this.$("#whohow option:selected").val());
      const filcode = this.$("#whohow option:selected").val();
      this.set("valuesIso", this.get('store').findAll('country').then((iso) => {
          return iso.get('ccode') === filcode;
      }));  
    }
  }
});
```

> My index.hbs calling my component

```
 {{country-list values=valuesIso }}
```

> my component handlebars country-list.hbs

```
<select name="whohow" id="whohow" class="form-control" onChange={{action "countryIso" }}>
    {{#each values as |item|}}
        <option value='{{item.code}}'>{{item.country_name}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

This is what Im expecting... When the user chose a country. I will use the iso code to look for a list of rates if they have the relation with that iso code. My code is not filtering well the data. With the code above.

[image: What Im expecting a filter...]

Comment: I'm a bit confused here. You pass your values from index to your component as `values`, then you loop them over. Then when selecting a language you set `valuesIso` which I can't see being used later (and you set it to a weird promise as well). How are the properties `valuesIso` and `iso3` being used later? Are those the ones not working as they should?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: https://ember-twiddle.com/0f2d60a3aad27ff1e181a9da7d68520c If so I can construct an answer explaining it all.

Comment: Helpful blog post related to this: http://balinterdi.com/2015/08/29/how-to-do-a-select-dropdown-in-ember-20.html

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren Im not using iso3 to make the filter, filcode is the var that im using to set the iso code with the selected country pick by the user, Im getting the value of that var with Jquery as you can see above in the code. Then Im trying to set valuesIso with the result of the filter, that isnt working.

Comment: @DevBlaster {{item.code}} - is this correct ? or {{item.ccode}}  - i mean cross check code or ccode property

Comment: @kumkanillam Yes it is correct, that field is in my webservice. I did a equal helper function and Im filtering the result in the template but is not a good solution. I think.

Comment: {{#if (eq item.code MySelectedCodeVar )}} {{item.country_name}} {{/if}} This made the filter but there must be a better way!

Comment: @DevBlaster instead of iso.get('ccode') === filcode; - try iso.filterBy('ccode',filcode)